# Ant Design Table Merge two Rows

Tags: reactjs, html-table, antd

[image]

I would like to merge these two rows when both the order numbers are matching.

I have a data like this

```
const orders = [
      {
        "_id": "64b271335aea2a06c83a25bb",
        "orderStatus": "Not Processed",
        "paymentIntend": {
          "orderNumber": "pi_3NU5ShHHJRov2Je41Us5hzVj",
          "amount": 40100
        },
        "orderedAt": "15-07-2023",
        "cartItems": {
          "_id": "64b271015aea2a06c83a25a9",
          "product": {
            "_id": "638193e3bd8d200b0b407b61",
            "name": "Frying pan",
            "price": 200
          },
          "count": 1,
          "color": "Black"
        }
      },
      {
        "_id": "64b271335aea2a06c83a25bb",
        "orderStatus": "Not Processed",
        "paymentIntend": {
          "orderNumber": "pi_3NU5ShHHJRov2Je41Us5hzVj",
          "amount": 40100
        },
        "orderedAt": "15-07-2023",
        "cartItems": {
          "_id": "64b271015aea2a06c83a25aa",
          "product": {
            "_id": "6381921e10b6f00add1d06e6",
            "name": "Random Stock Pot",
            "price": 100.5
          },
          "count": 2,
          "color": "Black"
        }
      },
  {
    "_id": "64b09ab4db9c3e065015ebc7",
    "orderStatus": "Not Processed",
    "paymentIntend": {
      "orderNumber": "pi_3NTa8DHHJRov2Je41M3g3df3",
      "amount": 600104
    },
    "orderedAt": "14-07-2023",
    "cartItems": {
      "_id": "64b09a94db9c3e065015ebb8",
      "product": {
        "_id": "633d3608ea9b06177e183399",
        "name": "Iphone 14",
        "price": 3000.5
      },
      "count": 1,
      "color": "Black"
    }
  },
    ...
    ]
```

This is what I tried to do

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";
    import {
      Col,
      Row,
      Table,
    } from "antd";
    
    const orders = [
      {
        "_id": "64b271335aea2a06c83a25bb",
        "orderStatus": "Not Processed",
        "paymentIntend": {
          "orderNumber": "pi_3NU5ShHHJRov2Je41Us5hzVj",
          "amount": 40100
        },
        "orderedAt": "15-07-2023",
        "cartItems": {
          "_id": "64b271015aea2a06c83a25a9",
          "product": {
            "_id": "638193e3bd8d200b0b407b61",
            "name": "Frying pan",
            "price": 200
          },
          "count": 1,
          "color": "Black"
        }
      },
      {
        "_id": "64b271335aea2a06c83a25bb",
        "orderStatus": "Not Processed",
        "paymentIntend": {
          "orderNumber": "pi_3NU5ShHHJRov2Je41Us5hzVj",
          "amount": 40100
        },
        "orderedAt": "15-07-2023",
        "cartItems": {
          "_id": "64b271015aea2a06c83a25aa",
          "product": {
            "_id": "6381921e10b6f00add1d06e6",
            "name": "Random Stock Pot",
            "price": 100.5
          },
          "count": 2,
          "color": "Black"
        }
      },
    {
    "_id": "64b09ab4db9c3e065015ebc7",
    "orderStatus": "Not Processed",
    "paymentIntend": {
      "orderNumber": "pi_3NTa8DHHJRov2Je41M3g3df3",
      "amount": 600104
    },
    "orderedAt": "14-07-2023",
    "cartItems": {
      "_id": "64b09a94db9c3e065015ebb8",
      "product": {
        "_id": "633d3608ea9b06177e183399",
        "name": "Iphone 14",
        "price": 3000.5
      },
      "count": 1,
      "color": "Black"
    }
    },
    
    ]
    const Index2 = () => {
      const [loading, setloading] = useState(false);
      const orderNoSet = new Set();
    
      useEffect(() => {
        orderNoSet.clear();
      }, []);
    
      const Columns = [
        {
          title: "Ordered Date",
          dataIndex: "orderedAt",
          key: "orderedAt",
        },
        {
          title: "#Order Number",
          dataIndex: "paymentIntend",
          key: "orderNumber",
//trying to merge here
          onCell: (record, index) => {
            const {
              paymentIntend: { orderNumber },
            } = record;
            if (orderNoSet.has(orderNumber)) {
              return { rowSpan: 0 };
            } else {
              const rowCount = orders.filter((order) => {
                return order.paymentIntend.orderNumber === orderNumber;
              }).length;
              orderNoSet.add(orderNumber);
              return { rowSpan: rowCount };
            }
            return {};
          },
          render: (value, item, index) => {
            const { orderNumber } = value;
            return orderNumber;
          },
        },
        {
          title: "Product Name",
          dataIndex: "name",
          key: "name",
          render: (_, item) => {
            const {
              cartItems: { product },
            } = item;
            return product.name;
          },
        },
        {
          title: "Price per item",
          dataIndex: "price",
          key: "price",
          render: (_, item) => {
            const {
              cartItems: { product },
            } = item;
            return product.price.toFixed(2);
          },
        },
        {
          title: "Quantity",
          dataIndex: "count",
          key: "count",
          render: (_, item) => {
            const {
              cartItems: { count },
            } = item;
            return count;
          },
        },
        {
          title: "Color",
          dataIndex: "color",
          key: "color",
          render: (_, item) => {
            const {
              cartItems: { color },
            } = item;
            return color;
          },
        },
      ];
      
      return (
        <>
          <Row className="mt-3">
            <Col span={24}>
              <Table
                columns={Columns}
                dataSource={orders}
                pagination={false}
                loading={loading}
              />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </>
      );
    };
    export default Index2;
```

Basically what I tried to do is create a set , if the order number is repeated , we get the frequency of the order number and then return { rowSpan : frequency of the repeated orderNumber} . For example the first Row with the "frying pan" and orderNumber pi_3NU5ShHHJRov2Je41Us5hzVj should return {rowSpan: 2} and second Row with the "Random Stock Pot" with the orderNumber pi_3NU5ShHHJRov2Je41Us5hzVj should return {rowSpan: 0 }

My above code manages to return the correct rowSpan. However , it becomes like this

[image]

Please kindly advise. Thank you.